# Grouping / Reduce array to a specific key of object

Tags: javascript

I've been struggling figuring out this problem.

So basically, i have this data (dummy)

```
[
    { user_id: 1, balance: 50, job: 'programmer' },
    { user_id: 1, balance: 20, job: 'teacher' },
    { user_id: 1, balance: 15, job: 'doctor' },
    { user_id: 2, balance: 5, job: 'doctor' },
    { user_id: 2, balance: 20, job: 'teacher' },
    { user_id: 3, balance: 100, job: 'teacher' },
    { user_id: 3, balance: 35, job: 'accountant' },
    { user_id: 3, balance: 40, job: 'lawyer' }
    { user_id: 3, balance: 10, job: 'programmer' }
    { user_id: 4, balance: 45, job: 'lawyer' }
]
```

And i want to reduce / grouping the array to be like this

```
[
    { user_id: 1, data: [{ balance: 50, job: 'programmer' }, { balance: 20, job: 'teacher' }, { balance: 15, job: 'doctor' }] },
    { user_id: 2, data: [{ balance: 5, job: 'doctor' }, { balance: 20, job: 'teacher' }] },
    { user_id: 3, data: [{ balance: 100, job: 'teacher' }, { 3, balance: 35, job: 'accountant' }, { balance: 40, job: 'lawyer' }, { balance: 10, job: 'programmer' }] },
    { user_id: 4, data: [{ balance: 45, job: 'lawyer' }] }
]
```

I've been trying to do it using `.reduce`

```
array.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const value = obj['user_id'];
    acc[value] = (acc[value] || []).concat(obj);
    return acc;
});
```

But it returns not as i expected.

Please help.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `Object` as your accumulator and `user_id` as key and than add values accordingly

```js
let arr =[{ user_id: 1, balance: 50, job: 'programmer' },{ user_id: 1, balance: 20, job: 'teacher' },{ user_id: 1, balance: 15, job: 'doctor' },{ user_id: 2, balance: 5, job: 'doctor' },{ user_id: 2, balance: 20, job: 'teacher' },{ user_id: 3, balance: 100, job: 'teacher' },{ user_id: 3, balance: 35, job: 'accountant' },{ user_id: 3, balance: 40, job: 'lawyer' },{ user_id: 3, balance: 10, job: 'programmer' },{ user_id: 4, balance: 45, job: 'lawyer' },]

let op = arr.reduce((acc,{user_id,...rest}) => {
     acc[user_id] = acc[user_id] || {user_id,data:[]}
     acc[user_id].data.push({...rest})
    return acc;
},{});

console.log(Object.values(op))
```

Comment: btw, this and the other object based answer could change the order of the items, if the key values is not already ascending.

Comment: @NinaScholz no that's true since now it was prior to ES6 [Ref article](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/) and here all the id's are numeric so it's not a problem here

Comment: object's keys are sorted by their numerical value, if this value is a positive 32 bit integer number. any other sorted array yields sorted keys.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and only a part of the object for the result set.

```js
var array = [{ user_id: 1, balance: 50, job: 'programmer' }, { user_id: 1, balance: 20, job: 'teacher' }, { user_id: 1, balance: 15, job: 'doctor' }, { user_id: 2, balance: 5, job: 'doctor' }, { user_id: 2, balance: 20, job: 'teacher' }, { user_id: 3, balance: 100, job: 'teacher' }, { user_id: 3, balance: 35, job: 'accountant' }, { user_id: 3, balance: 40, job: 'lawyer' }, { user_id: 3, balance: 10, job: 'programmer' }, { user_id: 4, balance: 45, job: 'lawyer' }],
    result = Array.from(
        array.reduce((m, { user_id, ...rest }) =>
            m.set(user_id, [...(m.get(user_id) || []), rest]), new Map),
        ([user_id, data]) => ({ user_id, data })
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are quite close:

```
 const hash = array.reduce((acc, obj) => {
   const value = obj.user_id; // typo?
   acc[value] = acc[value] || { user_id: obj.user_id, data: [] }; // initialize to an object
   acc[value].data.push(obj);
   return acc;
 }, {}); // <- use a plain object as accumulator

 const result = Object.values(hash); // turn back into array
```